# How I can repair an USB Drive mft and mftmirr?

Tags: ntfs, format

I have an USB Drive that I messed up. I've extracted it improperly, and now it doesn't mount. It has a NTFS file system and I used `testdisk` on it, but when I try to repair MFT with the Mirror or anything else, like reformatting it, it disconnects.

I don't care about any data on it. I just need a way I can use my USB again.

Also when i tried to use disks app, it gave me this error

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What happens when you try to use the "Disks" application to format the whole disk?  If the drive is still functional, it can be formatted and it shouldn't matter what's on it, or what you've done with it in the past.  If you cannot format the disk, then it's probably broken and not repairable.

Comment: When I try to format it with Disks app, it just disconnects

Comment: If i use testdisk on it, I can still list the files on it, even make an image of the USB, but i can't mount it, also says that  use chkdsk on windows, but it doesn't work too, also disconnects on windows too.

Comment: Maybe try a different port? Also confirm that there isn't a physical "read only" hardware switch. Since you have another OS you can also try to format it on Windows. If you can't format it with any utility on any port on any operating system, then it's probably dead and you'll have to throw it out. FYI: just because you can mount and view files doesn't necessarily mean it's not broken.